# How to write join select statements in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, postgresql

```
SELECT
    q1.user_id,q2.count,q2.total,q1.choice
FROM    
    (
    SELECT
        "table1"."user_id" as user_id,"table2"."choice" as choice
    FROM
        "table1", "table2"
    WHERE
        "table1"."user_id" = table2.ref_id                
    AND
        "table1"."active" = 1
    )q1
LEFT OUTER JOIN        
    (
    SELECT
        count(table1.*) as count, SUM(table2.add1) as total,table1.user_id as user_id
    FROM
        "table1", "table2"
    WHERE                   
        "table1"."type" = 1               
    AND
        table1"."some_id" IN(SELECT user_id FROM "table2", "table3" WHERE "table3"."user_id" = table3.refid)                
    group by
        "table2"."user_id"
    )q2        
ON
    q2.user_id=q1.user_id
ORDER BY
    q2.count ASC
```

I have one  query like this. It is working fine in db.But don't know how to write this in codeigniter using subqueries. Or is there any other way I could get the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$this->db->query()` for this..

[doc here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

```
$sql='SELECT
    q1.user_id,q2.count,q2.total,q1.choice
FROM    
    (
    SELECT
        "table1"."user_id" as user_id,"table2"."choice" as choice
    FROM
        "table1", "table2"
    WHERE
        "table1"."user_id" = table2.ref_id                
    AND
        "table1"."active" = 1
    )q1
LEFT OUTER JOIN        
    (
    SELECT
        count(table1.*) as count, SUM(table2.add1) as total,table1.user_id as user_id
    FROM
        "table1", "table2"
    WHERE                   
        "table1"."type" = 1               
    AND
        table1"."some_id" IN(SELECT user_id FROM "table2", "table3" WHERE "table3"."user_id" = table3.refid)                
    group by
        "table2"."user_id"
    )q2        
ON
    q2.user_id=q1.user_id
ORDER BY
    q2.count ASC';

$result=$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: and, you'll use $this->db->query() because CI's activerecord implementation doesn't presently support subqueries.